# How to print double quote in java ?? what should be syntax?

Tags: java

I want to print following line from which **A1** is string variable which is changing continuously.

**test: "a1" is mapped to Product. Cannot delete**

I used the following code to save the message in a variable `expectedMsg2` and print `expectedMsg2` but I am unable to print **A1** in double quotes, how do I print double quote? What is syntax for this?

```
String expectedMsg2 = "test: "+A1+ " is mapped to Product. Cannot delete";
```

Comment: how to use escape sequence ? can you elaborate???

Comment: @user1968880 In java you can do it by writing "\"

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ - they didn't bother to read your answer; what makes you think they'll bother to read your comment?

Comment: @DavidWallace That's true. Pity on my answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String expectedMsg2 = "test: \""+A1+ "\" is mapped to Product. Cannot delete";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `escape sequence` i.e. `backward slash(\)` to avoid special characters..

For Eg:

```
System.out.print("\"Hello\"");
```

**Output:**

"Hello"

Answer (score 1):

With java  `\` will Try something like

```
String expectedMsg2 = "test: \" "+A1+ "\" is mapped to Product. Cannot delete";
```

[`Tutorial from oracle on Escaping`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
System.out.println("\"Double Quote is Printed\"");
```

outPut:

```
"Double Quote is Printed"
```